# Content jumping when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have a simple nav-bar designed with flexbox like this :

```
<div id="nav-bar">

   <div class="nav-left">
       <div class="logo-contain">
               <img class="red visible" src="image01">
               <img class="white transparent" src="image02">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="nav-center">
       <ul>
           <li class="color01">01</li>
           <li class="color02">02</li>
           <li class="color03">...</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="nav-right">
       <div class="box-panier"></div>
   </div>

</div>
```

I made a pretty simple script that change the color of my nav-bar when scrolling and it's working fine. The problem is that when that script is called, the nav-bar does change like it's supposed to do but the img element move to the wrong place. It's supposed to be centered in the nav-left block but it's jumping to the right of the block. But if I open the chrome devtools and just change anything in the css like unchecking/cheking any css propretie, my img element is updating and go back in the right place, centered. So it looks like chrome isn't updating css well when my script is called.

Here is the exact same code in jsfiddle, exept it's working well here. I really don't know what's wrong because with the exact same code on my site is not working well.

[> JSfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/rosv7bg6/22/)

Comment: I think it's better if you provide a plunker so the question will be clearer. Anyway, if you use display: none on the class, other sibling html tags will collapse. use `.transparent { visibility: hidden; }` instead.

Comment: Please do not make long paragraph, it's difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I tried to edit my post and add a jsfiddle link to make my problem clearer.

Comment: Your second image doesn't jump right for me in the fiddle. It appears exactly where image 1 is. Seems pretty smooth to me in chrome. See screenshot https://imgur.com/a/PFBqVch

Comment: I think I'm bot being clear about my problem. The problem is only showing on my website but it's working well on jsfiddle and that the problem. How did you manage to make this video/screenshot ? I think I could explain way easier if I could post this kind of video of the problem

Comment: Its an app called screenflow https://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm

Comment: @Yuniru was this issue resolved?